# Return StatusCode with custom message

Tags: c#, http-status-codes

I have a C# application that can throw a locked exception. I'd like to return a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCode of HttpStatusCode.Locked and add a custom message to the response.

Currently in the controller if I use:

```
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status423Locked)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething(Guid id)
        {
            try
            {
                await MyService
                    .GetAsync(id)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (IsLockedException ex)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Locked, ex.Message);
            }
```

The it just returns the text of the exception message like:

```
The organisation 6ad1f1c0-2c47-4849-acbb-9eca56b568cf is offline.
```

However, if I change the return to:

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Locked);
```

It will then return the following response:

```
{
    "status": 423,
    "traceId": "|8f3060e2-4338773910204188."
}
```

So is there a way for me to keep both the "status" and the custom text in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a string when calling `StatusCode()`, use an object, and it will be properly serialized.

Example:

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Locked, new { status = (int)HttpStatusCode.Locked, message = ex.Message });
```